# Spring Security login from controller

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to login a user from a controller after the signup. My code in the controller is:

```
...
User user = new User();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(userVO, user);

userService.save(user);

List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("USER"));

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken uat = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
uat.setDetails(user);
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication userAuth = authenticationManager.authenticate(uat);

context.setAuthentication(userAuth);
 ...
```

in the line authenticationManager.authenticate(uat) I'm getting a BadCredential Exception and I have no idea why is this happening.

Any help?

The stacktrace is:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:130)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
        at com.gianu.test.controller.UserController.save(UserController.java:66)
        at com.gianu.test.controller.UserController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7ee64ba0.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
        at com.gianu.test.controller.UserController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f57bd9ca.save(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Show stacktrace, please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This exception simply means wrong password.

Note that if you configured password hashing `UserDetails` contains hash of password (as loaded from the database), whereas `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` contains plaintext password (as entered by user). In your code these passwords are the same, perhaps it's a cause.

Comment: thanks! this was the problem, I was using the password returned by the service (which is encrypted). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are using Spring Security correctly in the first place. You shouldn't be creating your authentication token or invoking the authentication manager in your controller. That is automatically handled by Spring Security. Even if you can get this hacking to work, it pretty much defeats the purpose of using Spring Security in the first place because you clutter your application with pointless security code. The whole point of using Spring Security is the seamless security integration in your application so that the application and the security are very loosely coupled.

I highly suggest you to check out the tutorial first before proceeding with what you are doing now: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

Comment: The reason of this code is because I'm creating a signup workflow, and after reading some post (e.g. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=12631). The authentication manager is not mandatory (now i'm trying only with the token). Is a better way of simulate a signup workflow without using the usernamepasswordtoken? Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong doing the signup workflow. I have a project where the users will create their own account and I basically store their username and hashed password in the database. And then, I let Spring Security to perform the authentication/authorization using DAO authentication provider that points to that database. If you are doing what you are doing now, then there's no point in using SS because you have to manually check each time the user visits your page whereas you could just delegate that task to SS to do the same thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that One of the fields required for processing the login (i.e., the  username or password) from your form is null and should be checked properly that if your controller passes those parameters properly with non null values...

This error is thrown from this block usually,

```
if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
        logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");

        throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
    }
```

this code is present in the class

***"org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"***

When the getCredentials matches null in if block, A **Bad Credentials** error will be thrown now as you see in the console stacktrace...